# Setting up an SSL certificate for multiple webservices routed through nginx and a GitHub pages static page

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, containers, github-pages

Alright so I've run into a situation which is well out of my expertise or domian. So here's my problem.

I have 3 Webservices which are deployed (as docker containers) on 3 public IP addresses. They are called `hackalist`, `core-api` and `cms`. Now, I wanted to redirect three of these http://wolfbeacon.com/api/core , http://wolfbeacon.com/api/hackalist and http://wolfbeacon.com/cms (basically 3 different endpoints).

So for this purpose, I assume I would have to setup an nginx server to delegate these client requests to the container IPs. That makes sense and I have done that locally.

Now, I have our main website, http://wolfbeacon.com hosted through GitHub Pages.

*Problem*: Setup on SSL certificate for them all. One certificate for them all and future webservices. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx is **reverse-proxy** server, which is, in fact, exactly what you need.

However, GitHub Pages don't allow you to configure their reverse-proxy, neither it supports SSL for custom domains:

> **HTTPS is not supported** for GitHub Pages using custom domains.

The quote from https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/

So, in order to achieve your goal, you have to have your own server to be set up in front of GitHub Pages **and** all your WebServices. I would name it `balancer`.

Then you install nginx on this `balancer` and set it up to serve responses for your main domain (wolfbeacon-dot-com in your example) and (optionally) to serve SSL. You will have to delegate your domain's Name Servers to this `balancer` as well.

You may then point to **the real** GitHub Pages URL for your website (like example.github.io) inside your `balancer`s `proxy_pass` directive.

Assuming example.github.io as the main deployment of static content for your website and example.org as the front page for all your content and services, you then start with slightly similar configuration to the following:

```
server {
  server_name example.org;

  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  location / {
    proxy_pass       https://example.github.io;
  }

  location /api/core {
    proxy_pass       http://{PUT_HERE_IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_core-api_SERVICE}/
  }

  location /api/hackalist {
    proxy_pass       http://{PUT_HERE_IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_hackalist_SERVICE}/
  }

  location /api/cms {
    proxy_pass       http://{PUT_HERE_IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_cms_SERVICE}/
  }
}
```

Once you are sure your nginx is serving your .com, just go ahead and enhance this config with `listen 443` directive and some additional directives required in order to serve over SSL.

Consult with https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04 for onward directions about how to configure nginx to serve over SSL from scratch.

Comment: How do I setup this 'own server'/balancer? This is an nginx server? Sorry, I'm really sketchy on the details, I'm reading up things myself rn. I'd really appreciate your (slightly more detailed )guidance if possible!

Comment: Would it be just easier to switch away from github pages? Like just have something static?

Comment: Yes, just any Virtual Private Server (VPS) with nginx installed. Here is the link for comparison of VPS providers: https://www.webstack.de/blog/e/cloud-hosting-provider-comparison-2017/ Here is the link for tutorial on how to install nginx on your VPS: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I added some brief example of where you have to start with configuring your nginx `balancer`

Comment: this config looks great. So I will be setting up an dockerized nginx container with this config on my server. Now what about the SSL?

Comment: added two more paragraphs about SSL